# Json data getting posted to the server but always getting "com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of"

Tags: android, json

I have written a program to post some JSON data to the server which is working properly as I am also able to see the data , but I am not even getting a response message and everytime I am getting an error:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

This is one record i had posted at 3:52 pm today

```
[
    {
        Answer: "yes testing",
        Date: "Tue, Dec 8, 2015",
        DeviceId: "deviceId",
        QId: "41",
        Time: "3:52 PM",
        TransactionId: "deviceIdTue, Dec 8, 2015T3:52 PM",
        UserType: "User"
    }
]
```

Code i have tried :

```
btnAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            answers = editAnswers.getText().toString();
            if (answers.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please write an answer", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    postAnswers();
                    editAnswers.setText("");
                } else {
                    showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet 
                    Connection", "You don't have internet connection.",
                            false);
                }
            }
        }
    });

 private void postAnswers() {
    Calendar in = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date dt1 = new Date();
    in.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d, yyyy");
    String dateval = sdf1.format(dt1);
    SimpleDateFormat stf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    String timeval = stf1.format(dt1);
    final String date1 = dateval.toString();
    final String time1 = timeval.toString();
    final String datetime = dateval.toString() + "T"
            + timeval.toString();
    final String transId = deviceId + "" + datetime;
    answers = editAnswers.getText().toString();
    List<Map<String, String>> listMap = 
    new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> answersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    answersMap.put("TransactionId", transId);
    answersMap.put("DeviceId", deviceId);
    answersMap.put("Answer", answers);
    answersMap.put("QId", questionId);
    answersMap.put("Date", date1);
    answersMap.put("Time", time1);
    answersMap.put("UserType", userType);
    listMap.add(answersMap);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new 
    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postAnswerUrl,
            String.valueOf(new JSONArray(listMap)), new 
            Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.d("JSON Array", response.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data
                posted"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Volley Error", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand where I am going wrong, because the `Log.d("Json Array")` is not getting printed nor even the toast message is seen when I press the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known issue with the Volley library. If a `JSONObjectRequest` returns without any response from the server (i.e., blank response which is common for post requests), then the `Request` cannot parse the response into JSON and throws an exception.

The only way you have to fix this, other than forking Volley and making the changes yourself, is by overriding `parseNetworkResponse` in your response object (similar to how you're overriding `getHeaders`). Here's an example:

```
@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

    if (response.data == null || response.data.length == 0) {
        return Response.success(null, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response))
    } else {
        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply , when i check for the condition as you stated i am getting an error here
 Log.d("JSON Array", response.toString());
null pointer exception : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Replace "null" in the Response.success call with "new JSONObject()"

Comment: this exception is happening because you're trying to perform actions on the JSONObject response that's coming back - which is empty. Sending an empty json object as a response (as I suggested above) will prevent a null pointer exception, but you could also check if the response is null and perform actions on it only if it's not null.

Comment: thanx alot for your help and a nice explanation